# HTML - remove extra pixels from table rows

Tags: html

Hy all. I have problem with my basic HTML code. My task is to combine 4 picture parts without wisible margins. Im allowed to use only HTML code without CSS elements, and I must use table.
My problem is that i can't get rid out of space between rows. I narowed out that border spacing comes from webkit browser table stylesheet. Is there a way using only HTML code to remove this spacing.
Forgot to mention picture sizes is 3 - 200px x 200px and 1- 600px x 200px

Chrome debugger shows that extra 4px is inherited from table stylesheet

```
table {
display: table;
border-collapse: separate;
border-spacing: 2px;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 2px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 2px;
border-color: gray;
}
```

P.s. If i set picture height="100%" and width="100%" than i achieve my goal, but im no shure is this a proper way to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>LR1</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--Using table without CSS-->
<table bgcolor="green" border="0px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td ><img src="p_01.jpg" alt="Part 1" width="200px" height="200px"></td>
    <td ><img src="p_02.jpg" alt="Part 2" width="200px" height="200px"></td>
    <td ><img src="p_03.jpg" alt="Part 3" width="200px" height="200px"></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td colspan="3">
        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan" target="_blank"><img src="p_04.jpg" alt="Part 4" width="600px" height="200px">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you set picture to `height="100%"` than you achieve your goal. You can keep defined with this.

Comment: Why put four pictures in a table? Why not have one picture? And why a table instead of divs?

Comment: My task states that i must combine 4 picture parts to get one big picture.  Must use table without CSS and use 4.01 strict !DOCTYPE. Go figure teacher's thinking =)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve your problem is adding style="display: block" to the image. The display: inline by defaults add extra space to the cell.

Comment: Without cellpadding or cellspacing atributes there is more extra spacing